# Django unit tests, custom permission and request.user.username

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I need to restrict access to the APIs I have defined in my view.  Here is my `views.py`:

```
rom rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework import permissions
from .serializers import LocationSerializer, PartSerializer, PartLocationSerializer, SiteSerializer
from .models import Location, Part, PartLocation, Site, SPIUser


class SPIPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    blah blah blah ...
    """
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        try:
            username = request.user.username
            SPIUser.objects.get(username=username)
        except SPIUser.DoesNotExist:
            return False
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return False
        return True


class LocationList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    # using get_queryset().order_by('id') prevents UnorderedObjectListWarning
    queryset = Location.objects.get_queryset().order_by('id')
    serializer_class = LocationSerializer
    permission_classes = (SPIPermission,)
```

I want to demonstrate in my unit tests that your have to be an SPIUser to be able to access these api endpoints so I write a simple unit test like so:

```
from .models import Location, Part, PartLocation, Site, SPIUser
from .urls import urlpatterns
from my.APITestCase import RemoteAuthenticatedTest
from django.db.models import ProtectedError
from django.test import TransactionTestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework import status
import django.db.utils
import os


class ViewTestCases(RemoteAuthenticatedTest):

    def test_spi_permission(self):

        url = reverse('spi:locationlist')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
        SPIUser.objects.create(username=self.username)
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertNotEquals(response.status_code, status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

This test fails with the this error message:

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/apps/man/apman/spi/tests.py", line 21, in test_spi_permission
    self.assertNotEquals(response.status_code, status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
AssertionError: 403 == 403
```

I noticed that the line in `has_permission` ...

```
username = request.user.username
```

... always sets the `username` to `''`.  So `has_permission` will always return `False`.

My unit test `ViewTestCases` inherits class `RemoteAuthenticatedTest` which is defined like so:

```
from rest_framework.test import APIClient,APITestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token


class RemoteAuthenticatedTest(APITestCase):
    client_class = APIClient

    def setUp(self):
        self.username = 'mister_neutron'
        self.password = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username= self.username,
                                             email='mister_neutron@example.com',
                                             password=self.password)
        #authentication user
        self.client.login(username=self.username, password=self.password)
        Token.objects.create(user=self.user)
        super(RemoteAuthenticatedTest, self).setUp()
```

So I thought that `request.user.username` would be `mister_neutron`.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah heck.  I forgot that I am using RemoteUser authentication so when I make my I need to set `REMOTE_USER` like so:

```
        response = self.client.get(url, REMOTE_USER=self.username)
```